# Excel vba Formula2R1C1 LET produces Runtime error 1004 using `r` or `c` as names

Tags: excel, vba, office365, excel-r1c1-notation

*I wanted to insert a formula in a cell, using vba.*

*I first used the recorder for the formula and after being recorded ran the macro and it did not work.*

*I then tried modifying the recorded macro to avoid it from being a `selection` or `active cell` related issue. But no luck there.*

I shortened the formula and found that the number of conditions seems to be related.

This is what I found:

```
Sub test()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Formula2R1C1 = "=LET(d,R4C1:R1008C3,a,INDEX(d,,1),b,INDEX(d,,2),b)"

End Sub
```

This works without errors.

When I add another `name` to `LET` it errors:

```
Sub test()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Formula2R1C1 = "=LET(d,R4C1:R1008C3,a,INDEX(d,,1),b,INDEX(d,,2),c,INDEX(d,,2),b)"

End Sub
```

This gives the following error:

[image: error]

I can't seem to understand what causes this error and I'm hoping somebody on here know what direction to think.

It's a Windows 11 Laptop (private) and running Office Version : 18.2301.1131.0

Edit: When adding `option explicit` it says:

[image]

Comment: Same for me. BUT: if you change **`c` to e.g. `x`** it works. Maybe `c` is somehow reserved? Same for your first formula: if you change `a` to `c` it fails .... But I don't get the compile error with 'Option explicit'

Comment: `c` - when using `R1C1` notation, means the current Column. I'm guessing that's the issue.

Comment: @CLR That sounds like the correct answer: when using `r` as variable name same error occurs!

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. @clr you could post that as an answer. Both thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to avoid using c, C, r or R as variable names when writing in R1C1 notation as they represent the current Column (c) or Row (r) and so you're attempting to load a reference to a column into a parameter that is expecting a single variable name.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the title so people that might have the same issue using LET() easily recognize this topic.