# Learning Excel 365's new array formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to get to grips with the new Excel 365 array formulas. Sometimes that are straight forward, but other times the results are unexpected. The lack of debugging tools makes them more difficult to learn.

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve.

[image: Source Data]

I'm trying to produce two different outputs.

[image: Outputs]

One is a simple cartesian product and the other a sum of the scores but keeping the original data in the first two columns.

I'm specifically not using tables as I'm trying to get the result purely with array formulas.

My attempt so far is:

[image: Attempt]

```
=BYROW(TAKE(R2C1:R4C2,,1),LAMBDA(_r,VSTACK(FILTER(R2C4:R9C5,R2C4:R9C4=_r))))
```

I use `R1C1` mode as it's far easier to deal with where the cells are and what absolute and relative references look like. Once you change from `A1` it's hard to go back.

Can anyone help me to get my two required outputs?

Comment: But where is this used in the function : `_r`?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - Sorry, I posted a function that I was trying to correct. I'll put it back.

Comment: Please try this formula : `=VSTACK(HSTACK(B1,D1:E1),HSTACK(XLOOKUP(D2:D9,A2:A4,B2:B4),D2:E9))` and second one, `=VSTACK(HSTACK(A1:B1,E1),HSTACK(A2:B4,SUMIFS(E2:E9,D2:D9,A2:A4)))`

Answer (score 3):

### Lookup Data

[image]

Learning about `BYROW` here i.e. Mayukh Bhattacharya's `SUMIFS` solution is more efficient.

**R1C1**

- Note that you cannot use `r` as a variable (someone else might not know it)!

```
=HSTACK(R2C4:R9C4,XLOOKUP(R2C4:R9C4,R2C1:R4C1:R4C1,R2C2:R4C2),R2C5:R9C5)
=HSTACK(R2C1:R4C2,BYROW(R2C1:R4C1,LAMBDA(rw,SUM(FILTER(R2C5:R9C5,R2C4:R9C4=rw)))))
```

**A1**

```
=HSTACK(D2:D9,XLOOKUP(D2:D9,A2:A4,B2:B4),E2:E9)
=HSTACK(A2:B4,BYROW(A2:A4,LAMBDA(r,SUM(FILTER(E2:E9,D2:D9=r)))))
```

**Structured References**

To make it dynamic, put the data in tables, e.g. `Names` and `Scores`, and utilize the structured references in the following way:

```
=HSTACK(Scores['#],XLOOKUP(Scores['#],Names['#],Names[Name]),Scores[Score])
=HSTACK(Names,BYROW(Names['#],LAMBDA(r,SUM(FILTER(Scores[Score],Scores['#]=r)))))
```

Comment: Your comment on the `r` variable inside LET not being usable when using R1C1-notation is a very good one. Same goes for `c` as they're read by Excel as ROW and COLUMN respectively. Same goes for adopting formulas to VBA (see more here https://stackoverflow.com/q/75246108/12634230 )

Comment: That's why I was using `_r` and `_c` for my row and column variables.

Answer (score 2):

May be there is more elegant approach, but this is what I have tried without using <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> helper functions,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G1</kbd>

```
=VSTACK(HSTACK(B1,D1:E1),HSTACK(XLOOKUP(D2:D9,A2:A4,B2:B4,""),D2:E9))
```

---

&,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>K1</kbd>

```
=VSTACK(HSTACK(A1:B1,E1),HSTACK(A2:B4,SUMIFS(E2:E9,D2:D9,A2:A4)))
```

---

<kbd>R1C1</kbd> notation:

```
=HSTACK(VLOOKUP(R2C4:R9C4,R2C1:R4C2,2,0),R2C4:R9C5)
```

---

And

```
=HSTACK(R2C1:R4C2,SUMIFS(R2C5:R9C5,R2C4:R9C4,R2C1:R4C1))
```

---

Changed <kbd>XLOOKUP()</kbd> to <kbd>VLOOKUP()</kbd> since its easier to adapt in this particular case. Credit: **[P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b)** Sir.

---

One more way instead <kbd>SUMIFS()</kbd> using <kbd>MMULT()</kbd>

```
=VSTACK(HSTACK(A1:B1,E1),HSTACK(A2:B4,MMULT(N(A2:A4=TOROW(D2:D9)),E2:E9)))
```

---

Comment: Another one using `MMULT()` instead of `SUMIFS()` inspired by lot of usages of `MMULT()` from @P.b Sir --> `=VSTACK(HSTACK(A1:B1,E1),HSTACK(A2:B4,MMULT(N(A2:A4=TOROW(D2:D9)),E2:E9)))`